# Deploying .NET satellite assemblies in specific folder

Tags: .net, localization, resources, satellite-assembly

I'm working on a C# .NET application and I'm performing localization with resource files.
I have culture specific resource files like:

- MyResource.resx;
- MyResource.fr-FR.resx;
- MyResource.ja-JP.resx;

After building, in the application root folder there are folders like `fr-FR`, `ja-JP` and so on.

Is it possible to move all localization resource files and folders into the same folder, for example `Languages`?

Update 1:

I solved this with the code below.
it seems that when i copy the application to another place, it can't load resources. As i can see, application.config file need to be there also. And if i make app.config as embeded resource, it doesnt working.

Is there a way, how to make this without the .config file needed in same directory?

Thanks

Comment: Is it a libray project, e.g. dll?

Comment: No, it's desktop application.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default the satellite assemblies are placed in the sub-directories directly below the executable file. If you want to move all the `fr-FR`, `ja-JP` and remaining folders for other cultures into the same folder `Languages` you can do it by adding the following entry into the application configuration file:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="Languages"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

This will indicate that when searching for assemblies the CLR should search in the default locations and also in the directory or directories specified by the `privatePath` attribute of the `probing` element. You can specify any directories that exists below the application executable file. When specifying more than one sub-directory you need to delimit each one with a semicolon.

Comment: Does not work for me: there are 22 language folders (+ the lib folder) inside the build/release/ directory.
Even with an empty build/release/ dir, right before you hit F6 to build the solution.
Absolutely unnecessary. (just need 1 lang)

Answer (score 1):

My ResX files under Properties are below:

- Resources.resx
- Resources.tr-TR.resx

I put the runtime information into application configuration file as described above but no change. still creating a tr-TR folder under the executable path, not under Languages folder. What possibly I'm doing wrong here? Thanks

```
<configuration>
...
<runtime>
...
</runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You need to move the folder yourself (I did it with a post-build step). The edit to your configuration settings only controls how extra assemblies are searched, not where they are written to.